# I am unable to run react native app when i upgrade compilesdkversion & targetsdkversion to 33 , but facing issue react-native-reanimated:downloadBoost

Tags: android, react-native

I am unable to run react native app when i upgrade compilesdkversion & targetsdkversion to 33 , but facing issue Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:downloadBoost' and it is executing failed after 96%.

[image: Error facing]

----------- android/Build.gradle ------------------

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
        kotlinVersion = '1.8.0' // Set the Kotlin version here
    }
    repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
       mavenCentral()
       maven { url 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2' }

    }
    dependencies {
                  
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

---------------- Graddle-wrapper.properties ----------

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Comment: What is your RN version?